# Copy & Transpose Data from one sheet & create a new sheet then paste the data into the new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in a certain format & I have been trying to copy the row values and transpose them using VBA.

I can get this to work for 1 sheet but not multiple.

Code used for a single sheet

```
Sub transform()


Dim wss As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")







Cells.MergeCells = False

ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 271), ws.Cells(9999, 350)).ClearFormats

'Loop to transpose all data

For i = 2 To 62
    ws("Sheet1").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 215)).Copy
    ws.Cells(5, i).PasteSpecial transpose:=True
Next i

end sub
```

I have gotten this far with making the code for the what I am trying to achieve with the second part.

```
For Each wss In ws
        For i = 1 To 62
             ws.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 215)).Copy
             Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
             ws.Cells(5, i).PasteSpecial transpose:=True
        Next i
Next wss
```

I want to now loop through all the sheets in the workbook and copy and transpose cells from each sheet into its own new sheet can anyone provide some guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* this might be what you're trying to do:

```
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

For Each sourceSheet In wb.Sheets
    ' Don't transpose transposed sheets
    If Left(sourceSheet.Name, 3) <> "TX_" Then
        ' Add the new sheet
        Set targetSheet = wb.Sheets.Add After:=sourceSheet
        ' Flag the name so it won't get transposed
        targetSheet.Name = "TX_" & sourceSheet.Name
        ' Copy source to target
        For i = 1 To 62
             sourceSheet.Range(sourceSheet.Cells(i, 1), sourceSheet.Cells(i, 215)).Copy
             targetSheet.Cells(5, i).PasteSpecial transpose:=True
        Next i

    End If

Next sourceSheet
```

Comment: This works 100%  thanks!!!, I only made a small change and that was to Set targetSheet = wb.Sheets.Add instead of After:=wss

Comment: Great! I'm glad you were able to fix the error. I've updated the code in the answer.